# expand function and calculate derivatives with deriv

Tags: r, paste, sapply

Here's the latex code for the function that I would like to expand and derive:

`$f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(x_i + \frac{h}{2}(1-ih)\sum\limits_{j=1}^i jh(x_j + jh +1)^3 + \frac{h}{2}ih\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n (1-jh)(x_j+jh+1)^3 \right)^2$`

[image]

I plan deriving for `n=6` through `deriv(expression(myfunction),c('x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'))`. I don't know how to compute the derivative without expanding the function but if there is a way please let me know.

My problem begins when trying to expand the function in just one string because part of the expression gets repeated so any help would be appreciated:

```
n<-6
myexpr <- sapply(1:n, function(i) paste( paste('x',i,sep=''),paste('+h/2*(1-',i,'*h)*(',sep=''),
                           sapply(1:i,function(j) paste('(j*h*(',paste('x',j,sep=''),'j*h+1)^3)',collapse='+')),
                           paste('+h/2*',i,'*h*(',sep=''),
                           sapply((i+1):n,function(j) paste('((1-j*h)*(',paste('x',j,sep=''),'+j*h+1)^3)',collapse='+'))
                           ,collapse='+'))


deriv(expression(myexpr),c('x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'))
```

Comment: "derive" != "differentiate."   Anyway, your code as written fails with a 'missing argument' error.  How about you provide a simple example of your sequence term definition?  In addition, do you really want a function of six independent variables?

Comment: This is just ridiculous. When I run that calculation, I then get: `object.size(myexpr) # 62425288 bytes`. R is _not_ a symbolic algebra system.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for trying, in any case I know my code is wrong, it should be shorter that is why I'm asking how to avoid duplicated terms, etc do you mena that the right expression gets to that size? maybe you could provide me with the code just to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been down voted for something I though that could be done. In fact, it is not only that could be done but also that R solves very fast:

```
z <- paste(
  sapply(1:6, function(i,n=6) {

    require(MASS)
    h <- fractions(1/(n+1))

    a <- paste('x',i,sep='')
    b <- paste('+.5*',h,'*(1-',i,'*',h,')*(',sep='')
    cc <- paste(sapply(1:i,function(j) paste(j,'*',h,'*(',paste('x',j,sep=''),'+',j,'*',h,'+1)^3',sep='')),collapse='+')
    d <- paste(a,b,cc,')')

    e <- if (i < 6) paste('+.5*',h,'*(',i,'*',h,')*(',sep='') else ''
    f <- if (i < 6) paste(sapply((i+1):n,function(j) paste('(1-',j,'*',h,')*(',paste('x',j,sep=''),'+',j,'*',h,'+1)^3',sep='')),collapse='+') else ''
    g <- paste(e,f,ifelse(i!=6,')',""))

    paste('(',d,g,')^2',sep='')

  }
  ),
  collapse='+')

deriv(parse(text=z),c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try something simpler to get a handle on working with expressions. In your case I am able to find an error in your construction of this (ridiculously large) expression by simply looking at the first argument.

```
> do.call(deriv, list(expr=parse(text=myexpr[1]), namevec=c('x1') ) )
Error in parse(text = myexpr[1]) : <text>:1:31: unexpected symbol
1: x1 +h*0.5*(1-1*h)*( (j*h*( x1 j
                                  ^
> substr(myexpr[1],1,40)
[1] "x1 +h*0.5*(1-1*h)*( (j*h*( x1 j*h+1)^3) "
```

So you are missing a "+"-sign in the expansion of the second term.

Strategically, however, I would ahve thought that Mathematica or Maxima would be better platforms to use for this purpose.